# RequestValidationMode 2.0 Configuration Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have to use

```
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
```

But when I use the above element in my web.config file then I get the following error:

```
<pages enableViewStateMac="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableEventValidation="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
```

[Screenshot of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E69bJ.png)

Comment: Please post the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Where is the screenshot? Buddy, edit the question & copy-paste the error you are getting...

Comment: @Daredev :Check now , i have added screen shot in question.

Comment: Based on your error, it's likely you have put two `<pages />` elements in your web.config, which isn't allowed - your app isn't starting up properly because the config is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used two `<page/>` tag in my `Wb.config` that was the reason of my error Thanks @dash to correct me.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below config:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="3.5" />
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```